# WKWebView Post Request Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, swift5, nsurlrequest

I am Trying to open URL with some post params in WKWebview using below code.

```
    //let postdata = strPostString.data(using: .utf8)
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string:posturl)!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let bodyData = "data1=\(String(describing: strPostString))"
    request.httpBody = bodyData.data(using: .utf8)!
    request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    jioPGWebV.navigationDelegate  = self
    jioPGWebV.load(request)
```

But not able to load Page .

Always getting nil httpbody in delegate method.

```
  func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
    print(navigationAction.request.httpBody)
    decisionHandler(.allow)
}
```

Please Help.